# Piping commands in a GDAL Docker container

Tags: gdal

I pulled Even's [alpine 3.4.0 container][1].  I can successfully issue single gdal commands but I was hoping I could pipe the output of gdal_pansharpen.py to gdal_translate to scale values to 8 bits all in one command:

```
docker run -v /my_dir/:/home osgeo/gdal:alpine-normal-3.4.0 \
sh -c 'gdal_pansharpen.py -r cubic /home/pan.tif /home/mul.tif \
/home/combo.tif | gdal_translate -of COG -ot Byte /home/combo.tif \
/home/combo_byte.tif'
```

Result:

```
ERROR 4: /home/combo.tif: No such file or directory
```

So it's like the gdal_translate does not wait until the output file is created.

Same thing happens if I try with a combination of vsistdout -> vsistdin.

Comment: What output are you wanting pipe? I thought the main output of the first command is the file combo.tif.

Comment: Thanx Robert.  I added more context above.  Everything works perfectly with or without the `sh - c` block if I do those commands sequentially.

Comment: At first glance I would use `&&` rather than pipe. Run second command if the first succeeded.

Comment: Works :-)  Thanx !